# Why IN() clause affects on one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
// mytable
+----+------+
| id | seen |
+----+------+
| 1  | NULL |
| 2  | NULL |
| 3  | NULL |
+----+------+
```

Now I need to make the first two rows as seen. Here is my query:

```
update messages set seen = 1 where id IN('1,2');
```

But it **only** makes the `seen` of the first row equal to `1`. Why not the second row?

---

Here is the output:

```
+----+------+
| id | seen |
+----+------+
| 1  | 1    |
| 2  | NULL |
| 3  | NULL |
+----+------+
```

Comment: It should be `update messages set seen = 1 where id IN('1','2');` or `update messages set seen = 1 where id IN(1,2);` right?

Comment: If the ID column is an INT, it shouldn't have changed any of the rows. as @RaunakThomas points out, the quotes in your IN clause aren't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '' in your "IN" clause.

```
update messages set seen = 1 where id IN(1,2);
```

Column `id` is an integer not a `character/string`

Answer (score 1):

Mysql will attempt an implicit conversion of the string '1,2' to integer and will stop at the first non integer character in the string so

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select 1 = '1,2';
+-----------+
| 1 = '1,2' |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

where the value returned is 1(true)
whereas

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select 1 = '2,2';
+-----------+
| 1 = '2,2' |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Returns a value of 0(false)

If you switched the values in your string to '2,1' then only 2 would be updated.